# Form maker plugin shows weird code instead of forms in my wp page?

Tags: wordpress, forms, plugins

I am trying to use form maker on my wp page but everything I try to show the embed form it doesn't work? In fact I get this weird code instead

{88d26cd087cfa9f683aff5413b56a3d609ebe56dd345f4402aa1780c7969ff6f}8 - Name:{88d26cd087cfa9f683aff5413b56a3d609ebe56dd345f4402aa1780c7969ff6f}
{88d26cd087cfa9f683aff5413b56a3d609ebe56dd345f4402aa1780c7969ff6f}10 - Email :{88d26cd087cfa9f683aff5413b56a3d609ebe56dd345f4402aa1780c7969ff6f}
{88d26cd087cfa9f683aff5413b56a3d609ebe56dd345f4402aa1780c7969ff6f}4 - phone:{88d26cd087cfa9f683aff5413b56a3d609ebe56dd345f4402aa1780c7969ff6f}
{88d26cd087cfa9f683aff5413b56a3d609ebe56dd345f4402aa1780c7969ff6f}12 - city:{88d26cd087cfa9f683aff5413b56a3d609ebe56dd345f4402aa1780c7969ff6f}
{88d26cd087cfa9f683aff5413b56a3d609ebe56dd345f4402aa1780c7969ff6f}14 - theme{88d26cd087cfa9f683aff5413b56a3d609ebe56dd345f4402aa1780c7969ff6f}
{88d26cd087cfa9f683aff5413b56a3d609ebe56dd345f4402aa1780c7969ff6f}13 - Message:{88d26cd087cfa9f683aff5413b56a3d609ebe56dd345f4402aa1780c7969ff6f}
{88d26cd087cfa9f683aff5413b56a3d609ebe56dd345f4402aa1780c7969ff6f}1 - type_submit_reset_1{88d26cd087cfa9f683aff5413b56a3d609ebe56dd345f4402aa1780c7969ff6f}

Has anybody seen these before?

Answer (score 0):

ok I figured this out, in case anyone could has the same problem. Wordpress was changing the "%" caracters form maker uses to embed forms with these weird code so all you have to do is replace all inside brackets (even brackets too) with a "%" to get the form back displayed